# Every once in a while

Tags: phrases, idioms, writing

Representatives from my recruiting company sometimes come to visit me, may be once in a six months in my office. Is it correct to write some words of appreciation to them as shown below?.

```
"I appreciate your thoughtfulness to come and visit me every once in a while".
```

Comment: I'd suggest this: "I always appreciate your visits!" (and stay silent on the frequency).

Comment: To me this is fine, though I am probably more tolerant of non-idiomatic writing than most, since I lived abroad for several years and am married to a non-native-speaker.  I would probably change "to come and" to "in coming to"; the only other ways I can think of to make it more idiomatic involve more drastic rewriting.

Comment: I am not entirely sure of your relationship with these people. You mention they are 'your recruiting company'. Does that mean they recruited you for the job and just stay in touch? It seems a bit unusual. Hence I am unclear about the message you want to get across to them. If you genuinely appreciate their visits I would say *I always appreciate your visiting me from time to time'.

Comment: That's fine. Try "once in a while" by itself to be less specific.

Comment: How about something like: 'I appreciate your continued thoughtfulness in taking time out of your busy schedule to come and visit me.'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with "every once in a while." However, you don't say "your thoughtfulness to come and visit," say "your thoughtfulness in coming and visiting." If you want to use "thoughtful" and "to come," you say "It's thoughtful of you to come and visit every once in a while. I appreciate it" (which sounds a little awkward to me, but that's a personal thing).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest saying this instead:

> I appreciate the thoughtfulness in your occasional visits.

Edit: As GetzelR said, the usage of `every once in a while` ends up sounding like it may be sarcastic and the replacement of it with `occasional` helps clarify that the speaker means occasional only in the most literal sense, without a hostile intent behind it. Therefore, it would be advisable to say that the `occasional visits` are appreciated, not the ones that come `every once in a while`.

Comment: I am not certain that this is better.  To me, it implies that the speaker only appreciates the thoughtfulness during each visit.

Comment: The issue is the implication in "once in awhile" of occasionally, not very often. It can be mistaken for sarcastic criticism

Comment: @GetzelR I see that when one says "once in awhile," but doesn't the current answer address that issue?

Comment: @GetzelR Criticism. OMG! I was also scared of that.

Comment: It does. You said "It would be better." I was just elaborating on why. I should have said that, I guess.

Comment: @MerinNakarmi What?

Answer (score 0):

I tend to agree with Blubberguy22, with the small change "I appreciate the thoughtfulness **of** your occasional visits". I think this eliminates the problem of the "during each visit" issue raised by phoog!